# Ink Filepicker drag and drop pane disabled after first upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angularjs-directive, filepicker.io

I am using `filepicker.makeDropPane()` inside a directive to make any div with an `ng-model` to a drop pane which saves the resulting InkBlob into the `ngModel`.

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("dropzone", function () {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      filepicker.makeDropPane(angular.element(element)[0], {
        dragEnter: function () {
          console.log("Entered dropzone");
        },
        onSuccess: function (InkBlobs) {
          ngModel.$setViewValue({
            key: InkBlobs[0].key,
            url: InkBlobs[0].url
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The first drag and drop upload will work, but once a successful upload has been made, any further drag and drop attempt will do nothing at all.

The `dragEnter` log message will no longer be called, which is odd, as I would expect a disabled drop pane to act as the rest of the browser window, whereby dragging a file on to it will just open that file in the given tab. But dragging a file onto the element after a first successful upload will simply not do anything -- neither `dragEnter`, `dragLeave`, `onStart`, `onSuccess` nor `onError` functions are called, but the browser doesn't open the file either. The browser does open the file when dragging it somewhere other than the given element.

I suspected that angular might be doint something here with the directive templating which is messing up the drop pane configuration, so I tried to recompile the directive in `onSuccess` by doing `$compile(element)(scope)`, however this had no effect.

What could be producing this behavior? It would make more sense if I had any feedback at all, but absolutely none of the provided callback functions are called after a first successful upload has been made.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the underlying reason why this was happening, and the following is probably just a hack around it, but just in case anybody else is in a similar situation, this is how I fixed it.

Instead of making the element with the directive into a drop pane (`filepicker.makeDropPane(angular.element(element)[0], ...`), I programmatically create a child `div` inside the element and configure that one to be the drop pane:

```
function create_pane () {
  var pane = angular.element("<div/>");
  element.append(pane);
  configure_pane(angular.element(pane)[0]);
}

function configure_pane (pane_node) {
  filepicker.makeDropPane(pane_node, {
    onSuccess:  save_img,
    ...
  });
}
```

Then, every time an image is successfully saved, I remove the child node and create and configure the pane again, which reinitialises the drop pane completely, allowing me to drop files in again:

```
function save_img (InkBlobs) {
  ...
  reset_pane();
}

function reset_pane () {
  emptyNode(angular.element(element)[0]);
  create_pane();
}
```

I got the idea from [Filepicker widget breaks after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663065/filepicker-widget-breaks-after-upload)